# Inconsistent behavior with mysql IS NULL operator

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a site built with Zend framework.

This  query:

```
$select
  ->from(table, new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(1) AS zend_paginator_row_count'))
  ->where("`resource_type` IS NULL)
```

In my local server returns a populated Zend_Db_Select object, but in my hosting's server not.
Instead of that, I need to modify the query to:

```
  $select
  ->from(table, new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(1) AS zend_paginator_row_count'))
  ->where("`resource_type` = '')
```

There is a reason or an explanation on why this happen? Obviously, the data is being inserted in the same way in both servers.

Thanks,
Lucas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the data is inserted in a different way after all, or the table definition is different. In your development server, your field might be nullable and/or not have a default value. In the hosting's server the field is different. It probably is not nullable or has a default value of `''`, which causes new records to automatically contain an empty string instead of `NULL`.

Note that in Oracle `NULL` and `''` are the same, but in MySQL they are two different things. So in your case the inconsistency isn't in the operator, but in the data.